# How should I write a whip sound?

Tags: word-choice, writing

Is it crack? Snap? Wh-tch? Whop-eesh?

Alternatively, if I don't use the actual noise. Do I write: The whip rang out? Cracked?

Comment: Whop-eesh for sure!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The sound is generally referred to as the *crack of a whip* or a *whip crack*, and since *crack* is already onomatopoeic, you can't go wrong with it. *Crack!* See. That hurt a little, didn't it?

Comment: This is, of course, only one of the many sounds that a whip can make. Specifically the one made by a rapid back and forth movement of the handle causing the tip of the whip to move supersonically. Whips can also slither, zip, slap, thump and make any number of other sounds.

Comment: But according to Snap it is Crack ;) _Like the crack of the whip I snap attack - Front to back in this thing called rap_

Comment: ...and you don't want that.  :)

Answer (score 8):

If we're coining onomatopoeia, I think sounds like *wuh*-PSSSH!

Comment: It's definitely a *kuh-CHHHH" to me heh.

Comment: Admittedly, the version in my head is from "Baby Got Back".

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be written, Ker-Chack! or Ker-Snap!